# Automatic flush of dhcp leases in Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, dhcp

I have a custom Linux device running a DHCP server. My DHCP negotiation is always very long (over a minute).

The problem is, the device does not have storage and the leases are flushed everytime the device reboots. When Windows try to obtain an ip address based on old leases, the server cannot simply give back the ip because he has no memory of previously giving it.

I'd like windows 7 to ignore any leases it previously had and ALWAYS initiate with a DHCP Discover instead of a DHCP Request

Comment: Have you tried "ipconfig /release" and then "ipconfig /renew" (both without the quotes) to see how what works out?

Comment: a cleint with an IP from teh DHCP server should always try DHCP request per rfc 2131.  If you have nonstandard DHCP you should expect issues with clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to put the dhcp server into authoritative mode as [described here](http://www.isc.org/files/auth.html)

I also had to switch from udhcpd to dnsmasq since the first did not support that parameter

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

The client should always ask for a renewal of its old address, that is part of the protocol so I can't see how you could configure Windows to not do it. Why is it a problem though? If the address isn't available then the server will refuse the renewal request.

If, for some reason, the server isn't checking if an address is available (typically by doing a ping) before handing out new addresses then you will be in trouble anyway because it will hand out addresses that are already in use to any client that asks.